# Convert to ISOString when saving on update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I'm updating my date on my textfield. When I update the date field it becomes this
[image]

But I want to achieve that when I update. The birthdate field will be like this only the date will update. [image]

Here is my code

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
name: "",
phone: "",
address: "",
birthdate: new Date().toISOString(),
gender: "",
messenger: "",
_id: "",


})

  const [isRedirected, setIsRedirected] = useState(false)

  const { _id, name, phone, address, birthdate, gender, messenger } = userData

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = getUser()
    getUserById("/user/" + user.userId, user.token).then((data) => {
      setUserData(data)
    })
  }, [])

  const handleChange = (name) => (e) => {
    setUserData({ ...userData, [name]: e.target.value })
  }

  //   let test = new Date(birthdate).toISOString()
  //   console.log(test)

  const clickSubmit = (e) => {
    const users = getUser()
    e.preventDefault()

    updateUser(_id, users.token, userData).then((data) => {
      if (data) {
        Swal({
          text: "Your information has been updated",
          icon: SparkWaving,
        }).then(() => {
          setIsRedirected(true)
        })
      } else {
        Swal({
          title: "User updated failed.",
          text: "The server encountered an error.",
          icon: "error",
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

Is there anything that's missing from my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might need to call `.toISOString()` before you call `handleChange` for your date.  Or instead call `setUserData` separately if you're already using `handleChange` from other places in your code.

Assuming you want the userData state object to contain the ISO date string, in the event handler for your date control:

```
const handleDateChange = newDateString => {
  setUserData({
    ...userData,
    birthDate: new Date(newDateString).toISOString()
  })
}

<TheDatePicker onChange={(e) => handleDateChange(e.target.value)} />
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed my issue. I didn't realize I needed to make another function. Thank you again.